# How to increase ArrayList size to 100% just like Vector

Tags: java, arraylist, vector, thread-safety

While changing some code based on SonarQube suggestions I get to know below lines:

> 3. Automatic Increase in Capacity A Vector defaults to doubling size of its array . While when you insert an element into the ArrayList ,it
>      increases its Array size by 50%.

---

Now I am wondering if I need to replace the Vector with ArrayList there is a chance of failure of normal execution of the code.

**Remember existing Vector is not doing any Thead-safe work.**

Question:

1. Is ArrayList capable enough to resize just like vector?
2. Is it safe to replace the Vector with ArrayList in any condition except Synchronization??
3. Is there any exact replacement of Vector (Not expecting the Thread-safety)

Please feel free to update the question or ask anything.

Comment: What failure do you expect?

Comment: [Vector is broken](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386275/why-is-java-vector-class-considered-obsolete-or-deprecated), you **should** use `ArrayList`, and if you need synchronization use `synchronizedList`.

Comment: In existing code a List (No maximum limit) of URL's has been added in Vector. I afraid if I use ArrayList that has 50% increment may break the feature.

Comment: I dont think it is broken. Its legacy code, we cant 100% sure of its EOL I guess. @Idos

Comment: @MonsterJava ArrayList will resize automatically to hold as many URLs as you want (assuming you have enough memory - but it won't use more memory than Vector on average).

Answer (score 4):

The differences between `Vector` and `ArrayList` are some like this:

1. `Vector` is synchronized while `ArrayList` is not synchronized. So, Vector is thread safe.
2. `Vector` is slow as it is thread safe . In comparison `ArrayList` is fast as it is non-synchronized.
3. A `Vector` grows as doubling size of its array in default. While when you insert an element into the `ArrayList`, it increases its Array size by 50% .

   - ArrayList:

     ```
     /**
      * Increases the capacity to ensure that it can hold at least the
      * number of elements specified by the minimum capacity argument.
      *
      * @param minCapacity the desired minimum capacity
      */
     private void grow(int minCapacity) {
        // overflow-conscious code
        int oldCapacity = elementData.length;
        int newCapacity = oldCapacity + (oldCapacity >> 1); // 50%
        if (newCapacity - minCapacity < 0)
           newCapacity = minCapacity;
        if (newCapacity - MAX_ARRAY_SIZE > 0)
           newCapacity = hugeCapacity(minCapacity);
        // minCapacity is usually close to size, so this is a win:
           elementData = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, newCapacity);
     }
     ```
   - Vector:

     ```
     private void grow(int minCapacity) {
       // overflow-conscious code
       int oldCapacity = elementData.length;
       int newCapacity = oldCapacity + ((capacityIncrement > 0) ?
                                      capacityIncrement : oldCapacity); // default 100%
       if (newCapacity - minCapacity < 0)
           newCapacity = minCapacity;
       if (newCapacity - MAX_ARRAY_SIZE > 0)
           newCapacity = hugeCapacity(minCapacity);
       elementData = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, newCapacity);
     }
     ```
4. ArrayList does not define the increment size . Vector defines the increment size .

   ```
       /**
        * The amount by which the capacity of the vector is automatically
        * incremented when its size becomes greater than its capacity.  If
        * the capacity increment is less than or equal to zero, the capacity
        * of the vector is doubled each time it needs to grow.
        *
        * @serial
        */
        protected int capacityIncrement;
   ```

Based above:

1. `ArrayList` capable can not resize just like `Vector`.
2. `ArrayList` is not thread safe. It can not replace `Vector` by `ArrayList` in multiple threads directly.
3. It can replace `Vector` by `ArrayList` in single thread mostly. Because The declaration of `Vector` and `ArrayList`:

   ```
   public class Vector<E>
       extends AbstractList<E>
       implements List<E>, RandomAccess, Cloneable, java.io.Serializable  


   public class ArrayList<E> 
       extends AbstractList<E>
       implements List<E>, RandomAccess, Cloneable, java.io.Serializable
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I don’t see a problem. The exact performance metrics of Vector and ArrayList are not the same, but for most practical purposes this is not important. The ArrayList will extend whenever needed, and more often than Vector (if you don’t tell it the needed capacity beforehand). Go ahead.

For your questions: 1. Yes 2. Yes 3. No